# JS Async/Await vs Promise vs Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, callback

I'm trying to understand difference between these 3. Callbacks & Promises are clear but I don't get the usage of async/await. I know it is the syntactic sugar of promises but what I've tried didn't work. I'm sharing the piece of code I've tried to understand all this...

I've tried with an array

```
var array = [1,2,3];
```

and 2 functions

- `get()` executes in 1 sec & console the `array`
- `post(item)` executes in 2 sec & push a new item in the `array`

Now, what I want to get is that the `post` method should execute first & `get` after it so that the result on the console should be `[1,2,3,4]` not `[1,2,3]`

**CALLBACK**

```javascript
function get() {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(array), 1000);
}

function post(item, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        array.push(item);
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}

function init() {
    post(4, get);
    // returns [1,2,3,4] ✅
}
```

It works fine but in case of too many callbacks, code will be messier... So,

**PROMISE**

```javascript
function get() {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(array), 1000);
}

function post(item) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
        array.push(item)
        resolve();
    }, 2000));
}

function init() {
    post(4).then(get);
    // returns [1,2,3,4] ✅
}
```

Ok with much cleaner code. But still multiple `then` calls... Now,

**Async/Await**

```javascript
function get() {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(array), 1000);
}

function post(item) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        array.push(item)
    }, 2000);
}

async function init() {
    await post(4);
    get();
    // returns [1,2,3] ❌

    await post(4);
    await get();
    // returns [1,2,3] ❌

    post(4);
    await get();
    // returns [1,2,3] ❌
}
```

Much more cleaner version but neither way, it worked... I've also tried this (convert both functions (`post` & `get`) to async and call with `then`)

```javascript
async function get() {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(array), 1000);
}

async function post(item) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        array.push(item)
    }, 2000);
}

async function init() {
    post(4).then(get);
    // returns [1,2,3] ❌
}
```

But still of no use. So I'm totally confused about this feature (i.e. async/await). Please elaborate on this very example. And also please tell me about `Promise.resolve` & `Promise.all` in this same context! Thanks

Comment: You still need to use the promise-returning `post` function when changing `init` from `.then()` syntax to `await` sugar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async` and `await` are tools to **manage promises**

> ```
> await post(4);
> ```

Here you are waiting for the promise returned by `post` to be resolved.

> ```
> function post(item) {
>     setTimeout(() => {
>         array.push(item)
>     }, 2000);
> }
> ```

However, `post` **does not return a promise**, so it does nothing useful.

You had a working implementation of `post` with a promise before. So use that:

> ```
> function post(item) {
>     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
>         array.push(item)
>         resolve();
>     }, 2000));
> }
> ```

Comment: Does it mean `async/await` is just a replacement of `.then()`?

Comment: Will it work if I user `Promise.resolve(...)` instead of `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...)`

Comment: Roughly, and no, because `Promise.resolve` returns a resolved promise so it will resolve before the timeout has finished.

Answer (score 4):

Your attempts with `async` and `await` do not use anything that resolves a promise *after a delay*. As it stands, all the `async` functions you have defined, return a promise that immediately resolves.

You'll want to use a utility function that you can often use. It returns a promise that resolves after a given number of milliseconds, using `setTimeout`:

```js
// utility function
let delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

let array = [1, 2, 3];

async function get() {
    await delay(1000);
    console.log(array);
}

async function post(item) {
    await delay(1000);
    array.push(item)
}

async function init() {
    await post(4);
    await get();
}

init();
console.log("wait for it...");
```

Comment: Thanks alot for utility function :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what you did in **PROMISE**.

Wrap post setTimeout in a promise and return it.
call resolve  inside the body of the settimeout.

```
function post(item) {
 return new Promise((resolve)=>{
   setTimeout(() => {
     array.push(item)
     resolve()
   }, 2000);
 })
}
```

then you can use it like that :

```
async function init() {
    await post(4);
    get();
    }
```

---

Comment: Great. My long lasting confusion is over now :)